# Why does the compiler fail to find the right type?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, roslyn, ambiguous-grammar

I have a method and a class with the same name. In a case, the compiler understands that I am using the class name, but not in another case:

```
using System;
using DTO;

namespace DTO
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Tests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

        private void Foo()
        {
            var foo = new Foo // Ok
            {
                Bar = nameof(Foo.Bar) // Not ok
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> CS0119 'Program.Foo()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

I get the same error with a static property:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static string Bar = "Hello";
}

// ...

private void Foo()
{
    var bar = Foo.Bar; // Error
}
```

If the compiler understands in the context that the `Foo` in `new Foo` is a class, why cannot it understand that `Foo` in `nameof(Foo.Bar)` is also a class? This notation makes no sense if `Foo` is a method.

Comment: This is a guess, hence not adding as an answer, but `Foo.Bar` would suggest a static property, which `Bar` isn't and so not something the compiler sees as valid. `foo.Bar` (lowercase F) is an instance of `Foo`, so `Bar` is a valid, visible property.

Comment: @Diado I tried with a static property, it triggers an error as well. I can add this information to the question.

Comment: @Boiethios Did you try `nameof(foo.Bar)`, just out of interest?

Comment: @Diado It works (if I initialize the property after the creation of the object, of course)

Answer (score 7):

In the first case the compiler knows you mean the class because of the `new` keyword. What follows `new` *has* to be a type name.

In the second case, there is no such restriction: `Foo` can be any variable, member, field or type. (Note that if this should work at all, `Bar` needs to be a `static` property of class `Foo`).

But since the method `Foo` is in the *closest scope*, the compiler thinks you mean this method group, which has no member called `Bar`.

Comment: Do you have an example where one can use a method's property?

Comment: Now, for sure, the compiler guys could write complex heuristics for this, saying that "OK, it might not be (the method).Bar, since that looks odd, and we can go find that there is a type named Foo as well, so we'll use that instead which makes the code compile", the first and foremost reason they didn't do this is that they didn't do this.

Comment: @Boiethios no, that's what the error message says: you cannot access "members" of a method group, that doesn't make sense...don't mix it with members of a `MethodInfo` retrieved via reflection or a delegate.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Hum, that makes sense

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I guess the reasons for not doing it are: 1) as developer you could be very suprised what is finally used instead of what you expected, 2) could be very expensive for very little benefit